# A word to describe someone's life span is shortened

Tags: vocabulary

I want to make a warning that sounds elegant using uncommon words, i.e. *it's dangerous to smoke and it makes someone's life span shorter.*

Here are some sentences:

> 1. Smoking makes your life span ephemeral.
> 2. Smoking makes your life span evanescent.
> 3. Smoking makes your life span fugacious.
> 4. Smoking makes your life span truncated.

Those are my best attempts. Are they natural? I need your correction and advice. Thank you!

P.S.: By the way, I have this uncertainty about the usage of those words [in the last of the sentence 1, 2, and 3]. Is it 'makes you [adjective]' or 'makes your life span [adjective]'. It has the same meaning in my bilingual dictionary. However, sometimes synonyms can be misleading, that's why I want to know whether they fit or not. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with "Smoking shortens your lifespan"? The first three of those words have the wrong meaning, and the last is used incorrectly.

Comment: Also, please tell us what research you've done already before asking this question, what you learned and how you found it unsatisfactory